# Can I use window.top inside the .js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am passing some variable from my gwt code to the jsp file. It is something like this

```
  <html>
  <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   alert("Inside the jsp file");
   var criticalPath = window.top.criticalPath;

   </script>
   </head>
   <body>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/flow.js"></script>          
   </body>
   </html>
```

What i want is to pass the criticalPath variable to the flow.js file. I know if, flow.js would be a method I could have pass the variable, but I don't want to do that way. Is there any way to avoid the method and pass the variable to flow.js or can I call the window.top.criticalPath inside the flow.js?

Comment: It's all in order, so a variable declared before the script is accessible.

Comment: This will work fine. :-)

Comment: @adeneo: So you mean to say, that there is no need to pass the variable? It will be by default accessible in flow.js(separate .js file)? Is that so?

Comment: Yepp, it's declared in the global scope, and unless there's some asynchronous magic going on that we don't know about, it's accessible inside the script as well. If it's good practice on the other hand is debateable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't place the variable `criticalPath` in any specific scope, which means it is a global variable, and hence it will be accessible from any js file (as long as they are loaded after `criticalPath` declaration.